# Java regex: how to find a short word inside a longer one

Tags: java, regex

I have a log file of which I want to ignore the lines containing /owncloud, find only the lines containing .html and print to screen only the url part. 
The original file look like this:

```
1.1.1.1 - abcdefg [01/Dec/2013:03:18:19 +0900] "PROPFIND /owncloud/remote.php/webdav// HTTP/1.1" 111 111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh) mirall/1.4.2"
2.2.2.2 - - [02/Dec/2013:17:28:29 +0900] "GET /img/bg_introduction.png HTTP/1.1" 111 1111 "-" "msnbot-media/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)"
3.3.3.3 - - [02/Dec/2013:15:46:25 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 111 1111 "-" "-"
4.4.4.4 - - [02/Dec/2013:08:54:13 +0900] "GET /xxxx/index.html HTTP/1.1" 111 1111 "http://xxxx.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
5.5.5.5 - - [02/Dec/2013:08:54:17 +0900] "GET /contact.html HTTP/1.1" 111 1111 "http://xxxx.com/yyyyy/zzzz.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
```

and the output should be:

```
 /xxxx/index.html
 /contact.html
```

I'm learning regex expression but I can't understand how to find a word when it's sandwiched inside other things. Furthermore I still don't understand yet how to cut the matches.
Here is how I'm doing it at the moment.

```
public class ParseLog {
   static BufferedReader input;
   static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(/owncloud)");
   static final Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(.html)");
   static Matcher matcher;
   static Matcher matcher2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path to file /access_log.txt"));
       String c = "";
         while ((c=input.readLine())!=null){    
            // Checks to the GET part
            String[] splitString = (c.split("\""));
            if (splitString.length >= 2){
              // if there is only 1 substring there is no "GET
              matcher = pattern.matcher(splitString[1]);
              matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(splitString[1]);
              if(!matcher.find() && matcher2.find()){
                 String parsedString = splitString[1].replaceAll("GET ", "");
                 System.out.println(parsedString.replaceAll(" HTTP/1.1", ""));
            }
        }
    }       
}
}
```

My question is:
Is it possible to do what my program does in 5 steps, **in one regex expression?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are overcomplicating things. Maybe try to find parts in your input that starts with `GET` and then have `/[no-space-characters]+.html`. You can wrap this `/...html` part in parenthesis to place them in [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Here is code example that gives you same result you mention in question

```
//one liner to read data from file (don't bother with it now)
String input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

//we want to find `Get /[no-whitespace-characters]+.html`
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("GET (/\\S+\\.html)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Output:

```
/xxxx/index.html
/contact.html
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much! I was overcomplicating things indeed.